# Gamma Pnl vs Vega Pnl

Tags: options, implied-volatility, option-strategies, gamma, vega

Why does Gamma Pnl have exposure to realised volatility, but Vega Pnl only has exposure to implied volatility? I am confused as to why gamma pnl is affected (more) by IV and why vega pnl isnt affected (more) by RV?

Essentially how do you show what gamma pnl will be mathematically and how do you show what vega pnl will be? I believe that gamma pnl is spot x (vega x IV - RV)

Also does gamma pnl usually dominate (in $ terms) the vega pnl of an options, as most literature is on gamma pnl?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For an option with price $C$, the P$\&$L, with respect to changes of the underlying asset price $S$ and volatility $\sigma$, is given by
\begin{align*}
P\&L = \delta \Delta S + \frac{1}{2}\gamma (\Delta S)^2 + \nu \Delta \sigma,
\end{align*}
where $\delta$, $\gamma$, and $\nu$ are respectively the delta, gamma, and vega hedge ratios. Then it is clear the vega P$\&$L has exposure to the change of the implied volatility $\sigma$. Note that, for the gamma P$\&$L,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}\gamma (\Delta S)^2 = \frac{1}{2}\gamma S^2 \frac{1}{\Delta t}\left(\frac{\Delta S}{S}\right)^2\Delta t,
\end{align*}
where $\frac{1}{\Delta t}\left(\frac{\Delta S}{S}\right)^2$ is the realized variance, and $\sqrt{\frac{1}{\Delta t}\left(\frac{\Delta S}{S}\right)^2}$ is the realized volatility. To see why $\sqrt{\frac{1}{\Delta t}\left(\frac{\Delta S}{S}\right)^2}$ is the realized volatility, we assume that, heuristically,
\begin{align*}
dS_t = S_t\left(r dt + \sigma_{Re} dW_t \right),
\end{align*}
where $\sigma_{Re}$ is the realized volatility and $\{W_t, \, t \ge 0\}$ is a standard Brownian motion. Then
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\frac{1}{\Delta t}\left(\frac{\Delta S}{S}\right)^2} \approx \sigma_{Re}.
\end{align*}

Consider the delta neutral portfolio $\Pi=C-\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}S$. Assuming that the interest rate and volatility are not change during the small time period $\Delta t$. The P$\&$L of the portfolio is given by
\begin{align*}
P\&L_{\Delta t}^{\Pi} &=  \frac{1}{2}\gamma (\Delta S)^2 + \theta \Delta t,
\end{align*}
where $\theta$ is the theta hedge ratio. For small interest rate, which we assume to be zero, $\theta \approx -\frac{1}{2}\gamma S^2 \sigma^2$ and $\gamma = \frac{\nu}{S^2\sigma T}$; see, for example, [Black–Scholes model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model). Then
\begin{align*}
P\&L_{\Delta t}^{\Pi} &\approx \frac{1}{2}\gamma S^2 \frac{1}{\Delta t}\left(\frac{\Delta S}{S}\right)^2\Delta t - \frac{1}{2}\gamma S^2 \sigma^2 \Delta t\\
&\approx \frac{1}{2}\gamma S^2 \sigma_{Re}^2 \Delta t - \frac{1}{2}\gamma S^2 \sigma^2 \Delta t\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\gamma S^2 (\sigma_{Re} + \sigma)(\sigma_{Re} - \sigma) \Delta t\\
&\approx \gamma S^2 \sigma (\sigma_{Re} - \sigma) \Delta t \hspace{1in} (\text{assuming that } \sigma_{Re}\approx \sigma)\\
&=\frac{\nu}{T}(\sigma_{Re} - \sigma) \Delta t.
\end{align*}
The cumulative P$\&$L, over the interval $[0, T]$, is then $\nu (\sigma_{Re} - \sigma)$.

Comment: Im stil confused about the gamma pnl

Comment: how could gamma pnl be  gamma pnl is spot x vega x (IV - RV)?

Comment: @Permian: See the above updates. Where did you get this? Can you please provide us the source? I would like to check the context.

Comment: Sorry but got it in conversation was confused myself

Comment: best explanation of getting from gamma term in ito expansion to the gamma pnl formula i've seen & frankly maybe the only one.

Comment: Hi, I know this post is awhile back, but the answer to the last question "Also does gamma pnl usually dominate (in $ terms) the vega pnl of an options, as most literature is on gamma pnl?" - is the answer yes or no? Because we started off with the gamma pnl expression but we ended up with the vega in the portfolio pnl expression.

Comment: @KaiSqDist: that would be another question. The approximation here is related to the realized volatility.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure this is a valid question!  Gamma p/l is by definition the p/l due to realized volatility being different from implied.  Vega p/l is by definition the p/l due to moves in implied volatility.

The second part of the question you have answered yourself.  Short dated options have more gamma exposure, long dated options have more vega exposure.

Comment: Its not clear to me at all how this is both by definition

Comment: What other explanation is possible ?

Comment: The connection between gamma and realised volatility, probably mathematically